# Generate foreman-installer-answers.yaml

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, foreman, puppetdb

Is there a way to generate a foreman-installer-answers.yaml file from a current setup?  After initially installing Foreman I changed a couple of things in the web interface and also used [theforeman/puppet](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/theforeman/puppet) and [puppetlabs/puppetdb](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb) to customize my setup (including puppet.conf).  I ask this for two reasons:

1. I am preping for upgrading to the next version of Foreman
2. I want to be able to reproduce this setup in Vagrant or on another server

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not really if you changed things in the web UI - if you'd re-run the installer with updated arguments then the file would have been updated.

If you're using theforeman/puppet, theforeman/foreman, theforeman/foreman_proxy, then you could create the file just by copying the parameters you're passing to those modules.

Comment: Part of the problem is that since my mods were done via the web UI I am not certain what flags I need to pass. I'd love to define all this so that I could enforce it via modules provided by theforeman... just not figured out how yet.